# How to get the field type of a parse_as_rest in web2py?

Tags: web2py

I'm using the REST functionality of Web2Py with the very handy function parse_as_rest. However, I need to do a special treatment when the parse_as_rest returns a unique row with a unique field and only if the field is of a certain type.

The function parse_as_rest returns:

- The pattern: the one that matched the request
- The response: selected row or rows with one or multiple fields
- The status: 200 if everything is ok

I can easily check if the response has a unique row and a unique field, but how can I know the type of that field?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to determine the type in the server on the client/browser?

Comment: No. I want to returned the field with a post process, but this needs to be done only on some type of fields and every single time that this field is found.